# How do I convert a dictionary from localStorage to an array of objects in Vue?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, local-storage, javascript-objects

I am attempting to convert a dictionary from localStorage into an array of objects. I need it to use the `.filter()` function, but I get a TypeError when I convert it.

It shows that `this.savedNews` is an array in the Vue console, but type-checking with `Array.isArray()` returns `false`. Also `typeof()` yields different results (see below):

```
  data() {
    return {
      savedNews: Array // -> case 1
     //savedNews: []  ->  case2 
    }
  },
  mounted() {

    console.log(typeof(this.savedNews)) 
    // case1 -> returns 'function'
    // case 2 -> returns 'object'

    if(localStorage.savedNews){
      let storedSavedNews = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('savedNews'))
      this.savedNews = Object.keys(storedSavedNews).map((key) => {
          return storedSavedNews[key]
      })
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredSavedNews() {

        console.log(typeof(this.savedNews))
        // case 1 -> returns 'function', then 'object'
        // case 2-> 'object', 'object'

        return this.savedNews
    }
  },
```

Comment: Don't initialise your `data` property to the `Array` constructor. Make it an actual array, ie `savedNews: []`

Comment: Also, `typeof` will always return `"object"` for an array. Go with _"case 2"_ and stop using the console for debugging. Your browser has a real debugger which is much more reliable

Comment: I've tried two different cases. The second is where I use `savedNews: []`. The results are above. `filter()` gives the same response for both.

Comment: `filter()` gives what response, exactly? I don't see any `filter()` in your code above. Please update it and include any error messages. An example of the data in `localStorage` would also be handy

Comment: Your first two comments helped me figure out the issue. I had to reorganize variable types/methods being passed between different components. `savedNews: []` was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize with `savedNews: Array`, it is just function;
Because it is not instance of Array Object, it is constructor.

```
typeOf(Array)       // function  (It is constructor of Array)
typeOf(new Array()) // Object    (Instance of Array)
typeOf([])          // Object    (Instance of Array
```